# Java Multiple inheritance, get rid of duplicate code

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

There are library classes B and C, both inherit from class A. I have 2 classes that extend B & C, namely MyB & MyC.

```
    A
   / \    
  B   C 
 /     \
MyB   MyC
```

`MyB` & `MyC` share lots of common code and they are only slightly different.

I want to get rid of duplicate code, how can I do this in java? In C++ it would be possible by creating a common base class and putting everything that is common in it as follows:

```
    A
   / \  
  B   C 
   \ /
  MyBase
   / \
 MyB MyC
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226364/java-alternative-to-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343840/favor-composition-over-inheritence):

- create a new class MyCommon with the common code
- add an instance of MyCommon in MyB and MyC and delegate the work to MyCommon.

Comment: gah beat me to it. :)

Comment: Beat everybody... ;-)

Comment: +1, good stuff. this is a helpful article that might be good to include in the answer: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2005/jw-1024-multiple.html

Comment: wow, this is the first time, i have seen +10 reps in less than a minute from answering

Comment: [This article](http://berniesumption.com/software/inheritance-is-evil-and-must-be-destroyed/) is what turned on the light bulb for me...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having all your logic in these classes, have all common logic inside class `D`. Now make it so that `MyC` and `MyB` each have a member that is an instance of `D`. That's called [*composition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Answer (score 1):

A class can only extend from one class.  However, you can implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you'll use something along the lines of:

1. Composition (pattern) to encapsulate instances of `B` and `C` "in" `MyBase`.
2. Refactor `B` and `C` (if necessary) to expose a separate interface, say `IB` and `IC`
3. `MyBase` to implement multiple interfaces: `IB` and `IC`, by "doing the right thing" to map methods on interface to internal `B` and `C` instances.
4. `MyB` and `MyC` to implement appropriate interface, and map calls to `MyBase`.